# Decoding USSD non-english response in python from a serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, ussd, non-english

I send USSD requests with python and print the response. My english response is correct but when the USSD response is not in english I get something like

> 97D34B7889877A547B49F9C600E12B944C6C9968D06DFC1855CC842014A0BBA6AE419C5109EC4E0A00

How can I get a Persian response?

my code:

```
phone = serial.Serial("COM4",  115200, timeout=5)
try:
    phone.write(b'AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*11#\",15\r')
    print b'AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*11#\",15\r'
    time.sleep(.5)
    print phone.readall()
finally:
    phone.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to re-encode your hexadecimal response:

```
hex_ussd = '97D34B7889877A547B49F9C600E12B944C6C9968D06DFC1855CC842014A0BBA6AE419C5109EC4E0A00'

good_ussd = unicode(hex_ussd.decode('hex'), 'utf-16-be').encode('utf8')

print good_ussd
```

Comment: For Python 3000: `good_ussd = bytes.fromhex(hex_ussd).decode('utf8')`

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you have specified a coding scheme "GSM 7 bit with unspecified language"
In your AT command, this is the parameter "15":

```
AT+CUSD=1,\"*140*11#\",15\r
```

See the specification document 3GPP TS 27.007 Section 7:15 for explanation of this.

That is OK for English, which can be defined in the 7-bit alphabet.
But since Persion can't be defined by the GSM 7 bit alphabet, I guess something like the following: the modem has received a string that is defined in some other way (by an 8-bit or 16-bit (UCS) coding scheme).  Because the modem either can't handle this language, or can't reconcile the string with your request for 7-bit coding, it simply sends you the whole string.

Have you tried separating that string into double octets (16 bits), and matching it to the Persian alphabet?  Probably you will find your message there.

To specify Persian, you could try 00010001 ("17"), and you would then expect to receive a string of 16 bit characters, pre-ceded by a language indicator.  But I think that essentially, that is what you already have.  So maybe you will have to do your own de-coder.

Sorry, more of an inspired guess than a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me. I'm using python gsmmodem and python simplesms.

```
pip install python-gsmmodem
pip install simplesms



from gsmmodem.modem import GsmModem
from simplesms import pdu as gsmpdu
PORT = '/dev/ttyUSB0' #Port your gsm modem is connected to.
PIN = None # SIM card PIN (if any)
BAUDRATE = 115200
USSD_STRING = '*140*11#'

modem = GsmModem(PORT, BAUDRATE)
modem.connect(PIN)
modem.waitForNetworkCoverage(10)

#encode ussd string
encoded_ussd_strint = gsmpdu.encode(USSD_STRING)

#send encoded ussd string
response = modem.sendUssd(encoded_ussd_strint)

#decode encoded ussd response
decoded_response = gsmpdu.decode(response.message)

print 'USSD reply received: {0}'.format(decoded_response)
if response.sessionActive:
    print 'Closing USSD session.'
    # At this point, you could also reply to the USSD message by using response.reply()
    response.cancel()
else:
    print 'USSD session was ended by network.'
```

Comment: It's an old thread but if you are having issues with pygsm then download it from https://github.com/adammck/pygsm and place it inside python site-packages folder as a module. It will link to your packages and the code will run smoothly.